# Unary ++ operator in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I suspect the answer is no, but is there any equivalent to the C++ unary pre and postfix incremement operator "++". For example.

```
int test = 1;
SomeFunc(test++);    // test is 1 inside SomeFunc and 2 afterwards
test = 1;
Somefunc(++test);    // test is 2 inside SomeFunc and 2 afterwards
```

I know about the Inc (and Dec) operator in Delphi, but you can't pass it to a function as in:

```
test: Integer;
//...
SomeFunc(Inc(test));   // compiler error, incompatible types
```

In addition to the compilation error, there does not appear to be a different pre and postfix increment. Its not a big problem writing code like this:

```
SomeFunc(test);
test := (test + 1);
SomeFunc(test);
```

but the ++ (and --) operators in C++ are a great feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no equivalent functionality built in to Delphi.

You might contemplate writing functions like this:

```
function PostInc(var Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Value;
  inc(Value);
end;

function PreInc(var Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  inc(Value);
  Result := Value;
end;
```

You would probably wish to make any such functions inline. Although it is open to debate as to how useful such functions would be.

---

Personally I feel that these operators are sometimes convenient in C and C++, but the case for them is not overwhelming. Certainly for beginners, they present a huge trap to fall in to as can be seen by the steady stream of questions here asking about expressions like `++i++ + i++`.

FWIW, your description of the operators is imprecise. You said:

```
int test = 1;
SomeFunc(test++);    // test is 1 inside SomeFunc and 2 afterwards
```

That is not correct. The variable `test` is incremented before `SomeFunc` is called, because a function call is a sequence point. So, `test` has value `2` if observed from inside `SomeFunc`. But the value passed to `SomeFunc` is `1`. This program:

```
#include <iostream>

int test = 1;

void foo(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(test++);
}
```

outputs

```
1
2
```

Comment: OK, thanks. As expected. How did you answer this so quickly, BTW? :o)

Comment: @AlainD 78 seconds is practically an eternity... I think David is connected directly to SO with a NeuroSky MindWave ;)

Comment: @David: OK, true enough is "test" is global, though I was referring to a local variable. Thanks for that comment.

Comment: Even for a local, the variable is modified before the function is called.  If you passed the address of the local to the function you'd be able to observe that inside the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, JFTR, the PreInc functionality is already available in a thread safe manner with `TInterlocked.Increment`.

Comment: @Uwe Yes, but not only threadsafe, inefficient. If the variable is not shared then using an atomic increment is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to pass the incremented value to the function you could use `Succ`, i.e. `SomeFunc(Succ(Test));`, but Test is not incremented afterwards.

Comment: Why would you do that rather than writing `SomeFunc(Test + 1)`? Anyway, the entire point is that the C and C++ operators change the value of the variable. I think that the asker already knows how to use binary arithmetic operators.

Comment: Isn't it fascinating how things can be made more complicated than needed :-) However, `Succ` is a more general solution as it works with all enumerations too. Personally I would also write +1 in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want function in delphi or pascal you can use this code:

```
function inc(Var TmpInt: Integer):Integer; overload;
begin
  TmpInt := TmpInt+1;
  result := TmpInt;
end;
```

Comment: This is no different to the suggested solution from David Heffernan